# Unable to check empty data in grails

Tags: grails

I have a data like,

```
def data = [[name : '', users : []]]
```

I try to check if the data is empty in various ways but it doesn't work anymore.
For example,

```
if(data.name == null){
   println 'empty'
}else{
   println 'not empty'
}
```

Or

```
if(data.name == ''){
   println 'empty'
}else{
   println 'not empty'
}
```

It's always print 'not empty'.
How can I do to check if empty ?

Comment: Did you intend on `data` being a `List` of `Map`s or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a List and `data.name` implies `data*.name` ([Spread Operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_spread_operator)).  So clearly checking against `null` or `''` wont work against a list.

So your check should be `data.name==[null]` or something alike.  e.g.

```
groovy:000> data = [[name : '', users : []]]
===> [[name:, users:[]]]
groovy:000> data.name
===> []
groovy:000> data.name==['']
===> true
```

To utilize Groovy Truth (where an empty string and null both are "falsey") you can just check, if all names are set with:

```
if (data.name.every()) print "got all names"
```

In case you just get the list there, but don't need it, the same rules about Groovy Truth apply and the following check would be enough:

```
 if (data.first().name) print "got name"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check `data.name.class` it will give you class `java.util.ArrayList`
which means you should access the `name` key using `data[0].name`.
so if you do:

```
if(data[0].name == ''){
   println 'empty'
}else{
   println 'not empty'
}
```

it will print `empty`

Answer (score 0):

As they all said data.name is a **List**. So does not make sense and is not possible to compare a list with empty string or null. Because the possible values of `data.name` are either an *empty list* or *list of strings*.

So basically to achieve what you need you may need to iterate over each item returned from `data.name`, like this:

```
def data = [[name : '', users : []]]

data*.name.every(){
    if(it == '' || it == null)
        println "Name is empty."

     else
         println "Name is not empty."

}
```